# jquery - active tab on page load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to have my 'home' tab active while loading the page. I tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me?

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-target]')
const tabContents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-content]')


tabs.forEach(tab => {
  tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const target = document.querySelector(tab.dataset.tabTarget)
    tabContents.forEach(tabContent => {
      tabContent.classList.remove('active')
    })
    tabs.forEach(tab => {
      tab.classList.remove('active')
    })
    tab.classList.add('active')
    target.classList.add('active')
  })
})
```

```html
<body>
    
        <div class="navigation">
        <li data-tab-target="#home"><a href="#" class="tab-link">Home</a></li>
        <li data-tab-target="#about"><a href="#" class="tab-link">About</a></li>
    </div>
        
    <div id="tab-content">
        
        <div id="home" class="fade-in" data-tab-content>
        <p class="text">This is home</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="about" class="fade-in" data-tab-content>
        <p class="text">This is about</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make "home" tab active initially, just add `active` class to its `<li>` element. So, your navigation tab should look like this.

```
<div class="navigation">
  <li data-tab-target="#home" class="active"><a href="#" class="tab-link">Home</a></li>
  <li data-tab-target="#about"><a href="#" class="tab-link">About</a></li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Javascript` is working fine just some `active` class & `css` get problem in your code.

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-target]')
const tabContents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-content]')


tabs.forEach(tab => {
  tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const target = document.querySelector(tab.dataset.tabTarget)
    tabContents.forEach(tabContent => {
      tabContent.classList.remove('active')
    })
    tabs.forEach(tab => {
      tab.classList.remove('active')
    })
    tab.classList.add('active')
    target.classList.add('active')
  })
})
```

```css
.navigation li.active a {
    color: #ffc107;
}

div#tab-content div {
    display: none;
}

div#tab-content div.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
        <div class="navigation">
        <li data-tab-target="#home" class="active"><a href="#" class="tab-link">Home</a></li>
        <li data-tab-target="#about"><a href="#" class="tab-link">About</a></li>
    </div>
        
    <div id="tab-content">
        
        <div id="home" class="fade-in active" data-tab-content>
        <p class="text">This is home</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="about" class="fade-in" data-tab-content>
        <p class="text">This is about</p>
        </div>
```

is working fine only some `css` are missing

Comment: Thank you very much!! It was indeed just the missing 'active' in class="fade-in active".